# Ajax Selecting and Sending a Form Dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a form over Ajax but having some problems figuring out the correct syntax in this case.

I have a div container on the page that has form objects added to it through an Ajax request and then some templating occurs before appending it to the page.  I'm using this code at the moment:

```
$('.summary-host').on('click', '.btnUpdate', function (event) {
    var form = this.form;
    $(this.form).ajaxForm({
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            $(".printArea").empty().append(data).css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });
});
```

`.summary-host` is the container and I'm trying to hook up the `.btnUpdate` to post the form.  When I click the button it hits the `var form = this.form;` line but the form is never submitted and there aren't any errors in the Firebug Console to give me any clues as to what is wrong here.

How do I get these forms to submit correctly?

I'm using the `.on()` method as I understand this will ensure jQuery attached to any new objects added to the container as well as existing form objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using "jQuery Form Plugin"

First of all you need to define 'ajaxForm' in document ready. Then define '.btnUdate' click event and in that submit form with Jquery submit() method

instead of this.form try to use Form id (Give id to Form)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#formId').ajaxForm({
             type: 'post',
             success: function (data) {
             $(".printArea").empty().append(data).css('visibility', 'visible');
         }
       }); 

       $('.summary-host').on('click', '.btnUpdate', function (event) {
             $('#formId').submit();
       })
    });
```

If you dont know formId then you can use jquery parent() method

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $($('.btnUpdate').parent()).ajaxForm({
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            $(".printArea").empty().append(data).css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });

    $('.summary-host').on('click', '.btnUpdate', function (event) {
         $('.btnUpdate').parent().submit();
    });
});
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: The problem here is that the Id's of the form are not always available at `$(document).ready()`  The forms are dynamically loaded.

Comment: Ok, If you do not have form id then You can locate form by using help of btnUpdate class and Jquery parent(). Assumming btnUpdate class element is inside of Form so you can use $('.btnUpdate').parent() method (User .parent() till you locate Form element). I have updated code for locating form element by parent method

Answer (score 1):

using ajax in submitting a form, maybe this might help you:

```
$.post(page_url,$(my_form).serialize(),
   function (data) {
      // do something here
});
```

1. page_url - the url where you will be submitting the data
2. $(my_form) - the id of your form tag like
                 `<form id="submit_form"></form>` will be `$("#submit_form")`
3. .serialize() - a jQuery function that creates string in standard URL-encoded notation
                    more info in this link http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

you can do this:

```
$('.summary-host').on('click', '.btnUpdate', function (event) {

            $.post(page_url,$(my_form).serialize(),
                  function (data) {
                    // do something here
            });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the submit event, it submits the form. The click event just catches the click on .btnUpdate but doesn't do anything with the form.

```
$('.summary-host').on('submit', '.btnUpdate', function (event) {
```

Comment: This just ends up submitting the form in a normal way without using Ajax.  Using `click` does post the form using the Ajax method